# JSON service is not getting in controllers

Tags: angularjs

I don't know what wrong with my code.

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
```

Please check this url
 http://jsfiddle.net/9budtfmo/1/
The JSON response is not getting in my controllers. If I have added the json data in the variable 'users' without using $http.get() method, it will work perfectly. But I didn't get response when I am using http.
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: promise unwrapping is no longer supported by Angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you open console you can see

---

### Error 404

We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.

---

which means your json file not exist

Comment: I cannot add my JSON into that, that's why I have commented my json format into that script.

Comment: please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/4KViK80iYprjM3XtVqA8?p=preview for working demo, it's not perfect as it calls getUser twice but that give opportunity to play with it a bit

Comment: @Vimal you're welome :)